# does Ubuntu 10.04 work with a KVM USB ports for mouse and keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, kvm-switch

I have see various answers and just wanted to know before I invest in finding a USB KVM.  I need to go back and forth between my Ubuntu laptop and Windows XP workstation.

I use USB keyboards and mouse.

Will this work and if so, is it dependent on a specific KVM?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without knowing what KVMs you have in mind. All I can say is that I have 3 Ubuntu boxes on an ATEN 8-port rackmount USB KVM with no problems and a further 3 on a Belkin USB desktop unit - all working fine.

Comment: I have an Edimax KVM switch and it works fine, too.

Comment: I'm looking for a recommendation on a KVM that works switching between Windows and Ubuntu, I have read that there can be problems....affordable would be nice, too!

Comment: Here were some comments I saw:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1189769  I am looking at an IOgear....